# must declare the scalar variable @TextBox1 asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

this is the part of the code that i am sharing for the solution of my new application.

when i execute this code,it throws exception "Must declare the scalar variable @textBox1"

```
public partial class About : Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=carpro;Integrated Security=True";
              con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Driver_Registration(Driver_Name,Driver_DOB,Driver_Address,License_Number,National_Insurance_Number,"+
                                            "Email_Address,UK_History,Contact,Occupation,License_Details,Taxi_License_Number,"+
                                            "Deposit_Details,Weekly_Rent) Values (@TextBox1,@TextBox2,@TextBox3,@TextBox4,@TextBox5," +
                                            "@TextBox6,@TextBox7,@TextBox8,@TextBox9,@TextBox10,@TextBox11,@TextBox12,@TextBox13)",con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver_Name",TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver_DOB", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver_Address", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License_Number", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@National_Insurance_Number", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Address", TextBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UK_History", TextBox7.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", TextBox8.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", TextBox9.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License_Details", TextBox10.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Taxi_License_Number", TextBox11.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deposit_Details", TextBox12.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weekly_Rent", TextBox13.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Label1.Text = "Registration Successfull";

            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox1",TextBox1.Text);

Comment: Never store your `SqlCommand` or `SqlConnection` as a field. Also use it as a local function and either `Dispose` of it in a finally block or wrap it in a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you are using in your `INSERT` statement are not the same parameters you are creating in your `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(..)`. Replace the `INSERT` parameters to the ones you actually created like `@Driver_Name`.

Also, you should move your

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=carpro;Integrated Security=True";
con.Open();
```

down to your button. Essentially you are only opening your connection once, then closing it on button click. Currently, there is no way to re-open the connection without re-starting the application.

Or better yet segment it off into its own class/function.
Or even better, setup the connection string in the web.config and call it from there utilizing dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

in your query you specify the parameters:

`(@TextBox1,@TextBox2,@TextBox3,@TextBox4,@TextBox5," +
                                            "@TextBox6,@TextBox7,@TextBox8,@TextBox9,@TextBox10,@TextBox11,@TextBox12,@TextBox13)`

you have 2 options

1 you can change your query to :

`VALUES(@Driver_Name,......`

2 you can change you AddWithValue to:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox1",TextBox1.Text);
...`